# Check window size on load and on resize with condition

Tags: jquery

I am building a script which requires to change the entire functionality of a certain script when the window size gets under 783px, so I've found the solution

```
if(jQuery(document).width() < "783" && myvar=="1"){
//do things for screens under 783px
}
```

But it only works if the screen is under 783px when first loaded the site, now i want to check on resize too since the css media queries work and it gets messed up. I need something like this:

```
if((document).width()<783 && myvar=="1" || onresize(document.width<783) && myvar=="1"){
//do things for screens under 783px
}
```

can anyone help me with this?
I've tried doing it with

```
jQuery(window).on("resize", function () {
//do my things for under 783px
}).resize();
```

But it doesn't seems to work, if anyone has another suggestion please share.

Comment: first of all change }).resize();  to  }).trigger("resize");

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/f4bLH/. Post the code from your resize handler?

Comment: @LShetty - `.resize()` with no arguments is a shortcut for `.trigger("resize")`. [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
function check() {
    if ($(document).width() < 783 && myVar === "1") { // use `===` and no quote around 783
        console.log("y");
    }
}

check(); // first-time check

$(window).resize(function () {  // no `on` here
    check();
}); // no `.resize()` needed here
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/LLWwR/2/)

Note: Wrap this whole in `$(window).load()`

Comment: That's actually quite interesting idea, it works just fine ! :)

Answer (score 0):

do it like this way

```
$(document).ready({
    //check windows width when window load
    if( $(windows).width() < 783 && ....){
        //do your stuff here
    }

    //when window is resized
    $(window).on('resize', function(){

        if($(window).width() < 783 && ....){
            //do your stuff here 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Attaching the resize listener to your window causes issues in IE (especially in older versions). In my experience it is best to attach them to your document or body.

```
$(function()
    var document = $(document);
    document.resize(function() {
        if (document.width() < 783 && myvar === "1") {
            // your stuff here
        }
    });
);
```